# Increase request timeout for GCP marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-status-code-504

There is this persistent 504 runtime error whenever I deploy a solution from Marketplace.

> "ResourceType":"runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter","ResourceErrorCode":"504","ResourceErrorMessage":"Timeout
> expired."}

The VMs started and work fine despite the error.

Initially, I thought it is due to not using default SA to launch the solution but I am wrong. I have the same error even if I use a default SA to launch.

I wonder is there a way to increase the request timeout for Marketplace? I have seen [guides](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout#command-line) on Cloud Run and GKE but not on Marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check your Compute Engine default service account to check if it’s **enabled** and if it has the correct **permissions**?

The default Compute Engine has the below format:

> PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Related:

https://community.bitnami.com/t/deployment-failed/59625

https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/Nr45fqKdGU4

---

Edit: For the **permission** in the SA, you need to wait a bit so the permissions can be propagated "may take up to 7 minutes for these changes to fully propagate across the system", [reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq#access_revoke).

Comment: Thanks Toni. As per my OP, I suspected is due to that too but apparently it is not. I have tried with enabling default SA with editor and with compute.instanceAdmin the same error persists.

Comment: Yes it is due to the SA. I should have waited for a while longer before deploying with the new IAM roles. Tried the next day and it works!

Comment: That's great. So the SA was missing permissions. Could you mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: Sure. Can you also highlight the requirement to wait for the IAM roles to propagate and I can mark this as the answer.

Comment: I have mentioned the permissions requeriment.